# 1215n asus: can't set correct monitor resolution (1366x768)

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I've just bought this little laptop, I've formatted it and installed Windows 7 Ultimate.
I've downloaded and installed all drivers from the website but I still miss the monitor one (generic plug and play is what windows assigned).
Looks like HannStar model HSD121PHW1

Any hints?

The max res I get is 1152x864 and both Intel and Nvidia drivers are installed fine.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the intel driver and re-installing it asking windows 7 to search the right driver on the internet worked great for me.